# finding divisors of every integers

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let S be the set of all positive integers n such that $n^2$ is a
>   multiple of both 24 and 108. Which of the following integers are
>   divisors of every integer n in S ? Indicate all such answers:
>
> 1. 12
> 2. 24
> 3. 36
> 4. 72

This can be solved by considering  different n which have squared divisible by 24 and 108. But in this way I must dividing each time with the answer choice.

```
 Any tricky way to get this question quickly?
```

Comment: I don't know about "tricky" but a straightforward initial approach is to simplify what you're given. In this case, combining the two divisibility conditions into one condition. Or maybe splitting the divisibility conditions into more conditions (one for each relevant prime) would be simpler.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that the least common multiple of $24$ and $108$ is $2^3 \times 3^3$.  Therefore, if we required that $n^2 = 2^3 \times 3^3 \times k$, for some k, then $n$ must be a multiple of $36=2^2 \times 3^2$.